# python neo4j create child after search

Tags: python, neo4j

Using python against neo4j,   I create a new node with parameters, this goes as expected.

I create another node with parameters, this also goes as expected.

I perform a search on the nodes with the parameter values from the first node, this returns a list of nodes that have the matching parameters.

my question is this....
looping through the result nodes from the search, how do I create a child relationship?

Comment: If you post an example of your code, it'll be easier to frame the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [neoModel](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If I already have the nodes in hand, I can use:

```
node_a.calls.connect(node_b, {'rel_prop_a': 0, 'rel_prop_b': 't'})
```

Where `calls` is the relationship type.

If I want one query to find and connect, I can use a query like:

```
MATCH(a: LabelA {prop_a: 't1'}), (b:LabelB {prop_b: 't2'})
CREATE(a)-[r:CALL{rel_prop_a: 't3'}]->(b)
```

And run it using a code line like:

```
query = '''MATCH(a: LabelA {prop_a: 't1'}), (b:LabelB {prop_b: 't2'})
    CREATE(a)-[r:CALL{rel_prop_a: 't3'}]->(b)'''    
results, meta = db.cypher_query(query, {})
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Cypher you could do it like this:

Create your two nodes:

```
MERGE (firstNode:Node {id:"first node"})
MERGE (secondNode:Node {id:"second node"})
```

Create a relationship between them:

```
MATCH (firstNode:Node {id:"first node"})
MATCH (secondNode:Node {id:"second node"})
MERGE (firstNode)-[:PARENT_OF]->(secondNode)
```